# How to define a method with custom invocation syntax "using" or "try" or "catch" or "set"?

Tags: c#, methods, syntax

What do you think?
I'm trying to create a `log` method. I'm wondering how to define it, with following invocation syntax:

```
logging(var loggerContext = new LogManager(input)){ // create a new logger context and store input 

   //var results = Method();

} // store results in logger context
```

How to implement logging??

Comment: Why are you trying to add a new keyword to the language?  Even if you can do that it would make the code a _lot_ less portable and nobody but you (with a custom compiler you write) would be able to support it.  What's wrong with just having a logger object with methods on it?

Comment: This isn't possible in `C#`, you can't define your custom language syntax, similar to `using`

Comment: I think you're trying to use a feature of the language that doesn't exist.

Comment: why not implement IDisposable and write 'using' keyword?

Comment: why & what are you trying to achieve by "logging(var loggerContext = new LogManager(input))"

Comment: @IOIOMAD: I have a developed project, and what I have to do, is to add a logging system. Foundation of this project is not AOP, and no logging framework helps. I want to log method input parameters and outputs with context of log. For example, method call hierarchy, called by and input parameters and returned parameters should log.
I want to minimize amount of code to be append to all methods. That's it.

Comment: @David: I'm not trying to add a new keyword to C#. I'm wondering if it is possible to implement something similar with `using` with delegates. The answer may be NO, It's not possible. Why you guy are angry with me?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative pattern I frequently use is something like this:

```
void WithLogging(Action action)
{
    // set up logging here
    action();
    // save results here
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
WithLogging(() =>
{
    //do some things here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have noted, defining new keywords is not something you can do in C#. You may find [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) interesting, particularly macros.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it makes sense to implement `IDisposable` for such cases with custom logic in constructor and `Dispose` method:

```
class Logmanager : IDisposable
{
    public Logmanager()
    {
        this.Log("Start");
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        // some logging implementation
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Log("Finish");
    }
}
```

Then you can put it in `using` statement:

```
using (var logger = new Logmanager())
{
    // you can add something to logger here, e.g. store results
}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone who will read this code would say it really makes sense.

Comment: Care to explain? I have seen this approach in a lot of projects and libraries. No sure that this is appropriate for logging purposes though, but at least it does not require adding new C# constructions)

Comment: I would agree with aush, and go a little further: I would consider this harmful. The using statement is associated with cleaning up resources. "Overloading" that meaning makes your code less readable and more confusing.

Comment: `IDisposable` is a pattern. When I see `IDisposable` I expect certain things, but this code is vague.

Comment: Guys, I totally agree with you in that such use of 'using' may violate the _principle of least suprise_. However I see no harm in non-standard usage of syntactic sugar language constructions as long as you understand what this code is being compiled to.